# Selenium: browser.visit(url) fails on linux but works on windows

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

I am running a simple splinter (uses selenium) script which does

browser.visit(url)

On my windows machine, the python script runs fine. However, on my linux server, the script will not run. It immediately stops at above and crashes.

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "test.py", line 57, in run
    browser.visit(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 53, in visit
    self.connect(url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/request_handler/request_handler.py", line 23, in connect
    self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/splinter/request_handler/request_handler.py", line 48, in _create_connection
    self.conn = http_client.HTTPConnection(self.host, self.port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 693, in __init__
    self._set_hostport(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 712, in _set_hostport
    i = host.rfind(':')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?Is that browser working?

Comment: yes the browser is fully working, I even tested out another python script, and that runs. so I think maybe something wrong with my code?

Comment: @PetrMensik omfg I was using `http:/` instead of `http://` lul

Comment: These kind of stuff happens to everyone :) However, if you have posted your code, you could have your answer sooner...

Comment: @PetrMensik I was about to update it with my code...then I realized the mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(this answer is here only to close the question.)

You were using:

```
http:/
```

Inside if your `browser.visit` method.. You forgot the ending slash!

```
http://
```